# How to use 8-cores CPU as a single-core more (8x) powerful CPU?

Tags: parallel-computing, multicore

I use python for my algorithm which uses only one core and I need more processing speed.

I have i7 6700K CPU with 8 cores. How to convert them to one core to have a total performance of 8 cores?

Multiprocessing and multithreading python modules don't fit in my case.

Comment: If there was an answer to your question, we'd all be happier! The point of course is that without parallelization, you *can't* make your program faster on multicore processors.

Answer (score 3):

Effectively, what you are asking, is how to take advantage of a multicore architecture without parallelizing code yourself. There are no ideal solutions for that, most likely, you will have to parallelize the code yourself manually; otherwise, you are bound to use a single core.

Nevertheless, there are a couple of things one can take advantage of:

1. If your algorithm happens to use other modules that already do the parallelization on their own, you might have to simply ensure the parallelization is used.
2. Look into some now-available semi-automatic parallelization modules, like [Pydron](https://pythonhosted.org/pydron/).
3. Look into some area-specific automatic parallelization modules, similar to [AutoParallel](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.11268).
4. Consider [automatic parallelization with @jit](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/parallel.html) using [Numba](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/overview.html). Numba is pretty powerful but may require you to rewrite a lot of your existing code.

In conclusion, there is stuff to explore, but there is no such thing as turning multiple cores into a more efficient single core.